# Difference between Convolution and Pooling?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

We uses filters in convolution that make feature map with reduced size(maybe), so does pooling. Then how are they different?

Comment: Simply, the operations they do, welcome to our community :)

Answer (score 2):

We use filters mostly to get different features(characteristics) about the object(e.g. image). And pooling we're using to reduce the size and at the same time to save the most significant information of each feature map.